# Update textarea with CKEditor + jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, ckeditor

I'm trying to validate a form which contains a textarea supported by CKEditor.
But now, it simply doesn't show any errors at all, and doesn't submit the code.

I've read all the answers I could related to this topic but I couldn't get my code working.

This is what I've got so far:

```
if(jQuery().validate) {
    $("#submit_button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();

        $(" #content_form ").validate({
            ignore: "input:hidden:not(input:hidden.required),input:hidden:not(input:hidden.editor1)",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.attr("name") == "editor1")
                {
                    error.insertBefore("#editor1");
                }
                else
                {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                editor1: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                imglink: {
                    url:true
                },
            },
            messages: {
                title: "The title field is required.",
                editor1: "The content field is required.",
                imglink: "You must provide a valid URL."
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I would be very grateful if any of you could help figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your problems is a fundamental misunderstanding about the `.validate()` method.

Your code...

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(e){
    ....

    $(" #content_form ").validate({
        ....
```

Since `.validate()` is the *initialization* method of the plugin, it typically gets called *once* on the DOM ready event.  It does not belong inside of the submit button's `click` handler event because the plugin needs to be initialized *before* the click event.  (*It also does not get called more than once, as all subsequent calls are ignored.*)  Besides that, the plugin captures the various click events and automatically performs any defined validations as needed.

```
$(document).ready(function() { // <-- DOM Ready event
    ....

    $("#content_form").validate({  // <-- Initialize the plugin on this form
        ....
```

**Basic demo of the plugin:  http://jsfiddle.net/EN3Yb/**

Comment: I swear to you I had it done back then. I must have fixed something in between and digging up in my mess I didn't notice this. I've read that .validate is the initialization method and valid method should be used in this case. Anyways, thanks a lot for showing me what I couldn't see anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The way I am doing is like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['txtSomeTextbox'].updateElement(); // this will update text in the hidden textbox that CKE is using.

// or if you have multiple instances 
// for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
//CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement(); // to update the textarea
//}
```

then, I get the value of the textbox as follows:

```
var mytext = CKEDITOR.instances.txtSomeTextbox.getData();
```

You can now use mytext to do any validation..

Comment: But the problem isn't about getting the data. I simply don't know why it isn't validating. I checked and its going at least until updateElement() line but the errors are not showing.

Comment: don't in a place to test the code right now but you sure your ignore selectors are fine?

Comment: I guess so. I found it while searching in other topics. Apparently, it is not ignoring required hidden fields and the hidden editor1. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: As I said, i am out of office for another hour. but please console.log your selectors and see if they return anything first..

Comment: Just tested bro. It is truly ignoring what it was supposed to. Editor1 is not in the ignore list and the inputs have values.